# Appending elements to a list in parallel table

Tags: list-manipulation, parallelization

Is there any way to store values in a list that is being computed in parallel? For example, if `ParallelTable` is computing some `{x,y}` values, how would I store those computed values to a list? The order does not matter. I can always use `Sort` later.

For example, the following calculation can be done using Table:

```
list = {};
Table[Block[{x = x2, y},
   y = 2 x^2;
   AppendTo[list, {x, y}];
   ];,
 {x2, 1, 2}]
```

This simply returns {{1,2},{2,8}}. But if I want to do this computation in parallel the calculation can't be stored in a list. This is obviously a simplified version of my algorithm which is very lengthy and I would like it to store in parallel.

Take same exmaple:

```
list = {};
ParallelTable[Block[{x = x2, y},
   y = 2 x^2;
   AppendTo[list, {x, y}];
   ];,
 {x2, 1, 2}]
```

This returns an empty list. It makes sense that appending to a list is not a operation that can be done it parallel since the kernal needs to keep track of the order in the list, therefore multiple kernals can't manipulate it simultaneously. But I feel like there is some way around that by avoiding the ordered property of the list.

Comment: Do you realize that `list = ParallelTable[{x,2 x^2},{x,1,2}]` would do what you ask? Do you have any particular reason for using `Table` the way you do?

Comment: Yes. I need `Block` or `Module` to be nested inside `Table` in order for the full computation to take place.

Comment: @Mike Having to use `Block` or `Module` still doesn't explain why you are using `AppendTo`.

Comment: What @Szabolcs said. `AppendTo` should be a last resort. If the list becomes long it will probably cost you more than you gain from doing it in parallel. Try to post a minimal but sufficiently complicated version of what you actually need to calculate, so we can help you with the actual problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `AppendTo`, you could just make list a shared variable and change your `ParallelTable` to a `ParallelDo`:

```
list = {};
SetSharedVariable[list];
ParallelDo[Block[{x = x2, y}, y = 2 x^2;
   AppendTo[list, {x, y}];];, {x2, 1, 4}]
```

Comment: Or replace `SetSharedVariable[list];` with `ParallelEvaluate[list = {}];` and then evaluate `ParallelEvaluate[list]` to get all values.